# Return list of string

Tags: c#, linq

I need to modify the method mentioned below to return list of strings . It would take contactid as input and should return list of questionnaires

```
public string GetFatcaQuestionnaire(int contactId, string questionnaireType)
{
    using (var context = new dbDealingContainer())
    {
        if (context.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            context.Connection.Open();

        var fatcaQuestionaires = context.FatcaQuestionaires.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ContactID == contactId && p.QuestionnaireType == questionnaireType);
        return fatcaQuestionaires != null ? fatcaQuestionaires.Questionaire : null;
    }
}
```

New proposed method

```
public List<string> GetFatcaQuestionnaire(int contactId)
{
    using (var context = new dbDealingContainer())
    {
        if (context.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            context.Connection.Open();

        var fatcaQuestionaires = context.FatcaQuestionaires.Select(p => p.ContactID == contactId).ToList();
        return fatcaQuestionaires.ToList();
        //return fatcaQuestionaires.ToList() != null ? fatcaQuestionaires : null;
    }
}
```

Actually need to return a list of only `fatcaQuestonaires`. `Questionaire` and not the whole `fatcaQuestonaires` object. Could some one tell me how to go about it.

Comment: in your second code bi, you are calling `ToList()` twice, user `Where` instead of `Select` its not the same as sql

Comment: If I remove the Tolist from fatcaQuestionaires.ToList(); I get an error. It says cannot convert Systems.Collections.Generic.List<bool> to Systems.Collections.Generic.List<string>. As I mentioned I need to send a list of fatcaQuestonaires.Questionaire and  and not fatcaQuestonaires. But I dont seem to be getting Questionaire  after the dot after converting to list

Comment: I have updated my answer below, I will update it to return Questionaire

Comment: btw is this Fatca the IRS form ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project out the property you want with .Select(x => x.MyProp);

```
return fatcaQuestionaires.Select(x => x.Questionaire).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6):

Using Linq, first you can do a `Where` filtering the desired rows, and then `Select` to projecting only Questionaire properties.

Try this

```
return context.FatcaQuestionaires
    .Where(p => p.ContactID == contactId)
    .Select(p => p.Questionaire)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

You *almost* have it. `Select` invokes a transformation function, so it is just making a list of `bool`. You need a `Where` clause to do the filtering, and *then* a `Select`.

```
var fatcaQuestionaires = context.FatcaQuestionaires
                        .Where(p => p.ContactID == contactId)
                        .Select(p => p.Quentionaire);

return fatcaQuestionaires.ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have written looks like it will return a list of booleans and not compile.  What you need is a combination of a `where` clause and a `select` clause.

```
return context.FatcaQuestionaires
    .Where(p => p.ContactID == contactId)
    .Select(p => p.Questionaire).ToList();
```

`Where()` is what limits the FactaQuesntionaires, and `Select()` is where you choose the property to return.  You can also write it like this:

```
return (from p in context.FatcaQuestionaires
        where p.ContactID == contactId
        select p.Questionaire).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `Select` to `Where` as I mentioned in my comment. `Select` will just return a bool value for every entry's evaluation base on your lambda expression. 
So you end up with a `List<bool>`

```
 var fatcaQuestionaires = context.FatcaQuestionaires
    .Where(p => p.ContactID == contactId)
    .Select(q=>q.Questionaire).ToList();
 return fatcaQuestionaires;
```